# Onload Javascript wont change DIV styles

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I am unable to make a onload function change my divider style... please can some one point out the error in my code?

```
function cpage() {

javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.width='0px';

javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.margin-left='100%';

javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.visibility='hidden';

javascript:document.getElementById('g-main').style.width='100%';


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I check the browser console, there is an error:

> Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Maybe you should change:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.margin-left='100%';
```

to

```
javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.marginLeft='100%';
```

Comment: No, doesnt work. I have even added in the header <script src="" ect. type java script to see if it can help but the problem remains not to effect ayything....

Comment: @brigitte18 Do you see any errors in the browser console? What happens when you place your javascript in a `<script>` tag just before the `</body>`?

Comment: i see errors from different things, but nothing happenes when i add it before the body tags

Comment: Here is the page, http://luogocomune.net/LC/index.php/20-varie/4290-benvenuti-sul-nuovo-sito#comments i am trying to make the right collum dissapear and stretch the middle one on load.

Comment: If I look at the source of the page, I see that you are looking for this element: `<aside id="g-aside">`.

That element is in the source after the call to `javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside')` so I don't think that is going to work. I also see that the onload is in a div: `<div id="comments-list" class="comments-list" onload="cpage();">` I am not so sure that will work. 

But I see that jquery is being used. I see this in the source: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`
What if you trigger your cpage() function in there? (And move your cpage() function inside the `<head>`)

Comment: ooooooh wow wow thanks!!! im a noob :) its 12:30 at night here so ill try in the morning and give you the answer checkmark! Most definalty you are correct sir! thanks thanks thanks

Comment: Is there a way to trigger using the jquery but only on the pages with comments? Like if the div <div id="comments-list" class="comments-list"  is present to run the function?? This way i can maintain the homepage format and when someone opens an article which has comments it will restructure the page

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($("#comments").hasClass("comments-list")) {
    $('#g-aside').css('width','0px');
    $('#g-aside').css('marginleft','100%');
    $('#g-aside').css('visibility','hidden');
    $('#g-main').css('width','100%');
}
</script>
```

Thanks! This seems to do the trick in the header, im giving you the answer check because you deserve it :)